# Assertion failed on git-svn checkout

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to checkout a svn repository with git using the following command on Windows 7:

```
git.exe svn clone "https://..." "D:\repo"
```

However, no matter what other options I try to use, the following error occurs:

> svn: E235000: In file 'subversion/bindings/swig/perl/libsvn_swig_perl/swigutil_pl.c' line 1666: assertion failed (get_current_pool_cb != NULL)

I am using the newest git version 2.27.0

Any ideas what could be the issue here? 
Is ist possible, that the https authentication of the svn link is the reason for this?

I also have svn version 1.13.0 installed. Can there be incompatibel cross references between svn and git?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have the exact same issue on Windows 10 and sadly no real solution for you. But maybe it helps in the meantime to install the prior version 2.26.2. [Link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.26.2.windows.1)

In my case it "solved" the problem until a proper solution is found.

### Update (2020-07-21):

Currently a release candidate for version 2.28.0 exists where this problem was fixed. [Link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: Ok thank you. So this might be an issu of the new release? I will try to report it to the git mailing list.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2649

Comment: When I came across this answer, I didn't feel so alone on the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is a known bug in the 2.27.0 Release and is Fixed in Higher Versions See https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2649

Until then you can roll back to 2.26.2 if you are unwilling to take a prerelease (it is fixed as of the July 7th 2020 Prerelease).